# How to change colour of successive user inputted words based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, modulus

I need to basically have five **checkboxes**, all with different colors. Whatever the user types in after clicking needs to be printed to the screen as successive colors based on what boxes are checked. Ie: If blue and yellow are ticked then the first word will be blue and the second yellow, third blue and fourth yellow.. If three boxes are ticked, a looping trio of colors will be seen and so on up to to 5 boxes!

My plan was to take the text the user wrote and put it into an array. Then using a for loop I want to increment through and use `document.createElement('div')`  and append these words into a container (the parent div) on the body.

```
function colourCode() {

        var userArray = [];
        var userText = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
        userArray.push(userText);

        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");                

            div.innerHTML = (userArray[i]);                

            container.appendChild(div);
```

This works fine.

Then I wanted to use an if statement to change the colour if the box is checked.

```
if (document.getElementById("cbox1").checked === true) {

    document.getElementById("container").style.color = "Blue";

}
```

This changes the whole sentance blue, even if other boxes are checked. In fact it changes the color to whichever box is checked first.

I thought about somehow implementing a modulus operator that might loop through the checkboxes at the same time the word is appended from the array, but no idea how.

Anyone got any ideas?

Also, **jQuery** is **not** an option!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet.

Push your selected colors inside an array and select them following the index of your words

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var blue = document.getElementById("checkboxBlue");
var yellow = document.getElementById("checkboxYellow");
var red = document.getElementById("checkBoxRed");

function colourCode() {
  container.innerHTML = ""; //Reset text

  //Push all the colors selected
  var colorsArray = [];
  if (blue.checked)
    colorsArray.push("blue");
  if (yellow.checked)
    colorsArray.push("yellow");
  if (red.checked)
    colorsArray.push("red");

  var words = document.getElementById("textArea").value.trim().split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let color = colorsArray[i % colorsArray.length]; //Take the correct color
    container.innerHTML += "<span style=\"color:" + color + "\">" + words[i] + " </span>"; //Add span with the word in correct color
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxBlue">Blue
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxYellow">Yellow
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxRed">Red
<br>
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="colourCode()">Generate</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```